# Issue displaying text if between two integers

Tags: php, csv, if-statement, integer

Still trying to learn PHP, and I'm making a digital display for a homebrew bar setup I have and have a bit of code that should reading a CSV containing 5 beers, and spitting out the data for each beer. I have no issues parsing the CSV, displaying the strings and integers using echo, but when I tried to use an if statement, it starts spitting out the code as text

Here's my snippet of code:

```
        <? if ($ibu['Beer1'] >= 1 && $ibu['Beer1'] <= 25):?>        
    Slightly bitter
    <? elseif ($ibu['Beer1'] >= 26 && $ibu['Beer1'] <= 50) :?>
    Kind of bitter
    <? elseif ($ibu['Beer1'] >= 51) :?>
    Very bitter
    <? endif;?>
```

What I get when I load the page is this:

```
= 1 && $ibu['Beer1'] <=25):?> slightly bitter= 26 && $ibu['Beer1']<=50:?>Kind ofbitter=51):?>Very bitter
```

So it seems to be reading the "if" and "elseif" but spitting out everything else as text. As I said, I'm still teaching myself so I'm not entirely sure what could be causing it.

Comment: Make sure you have integer values? or try with `(int) $ibu['Beer1']`

Comment: Either use `<?php` as described in the answers or enable short tags (although that functionality will be removed in PHP8) as described in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention the `php` after question mark
Do this:

```
    <?php if ($ibu['Beer1'] >= 1 && $ibu['Beer1'] <= 25):?>        
    Slightly bitter
    <?php elseif ($ibu['Beer1'] >= 26 && $ibu['Beer1'] <= 50): ?>
    Kind of bitter
    <?php elseif ($ibu['Beer1'] >= 51): ?>
    Very bitter
    <?php endif;?>
```